# Entering values repeatedly and presenting the total and average of odd numbers up to the number that have been entered

Tags: python

```
sum = 0 
len = 0
while True:
    number = int(input())
    if number % 2 ==1:
        print(number)
        sum += number
        len += 1
    elif number == "":
        break
avg = sum/len
print(avg)
```

Getting this Type error saying not all arguments are converted during string formatting.

Comment: How are you entering your values?

Comment: Just add `try...except ValueError` around your `int(input())` so, you can skip errors caused by number wrongly entered from keyboard

Comment: You wouldn't get that error ("not all arguments are converted") from this code, but you would get an error from `int(input())` if you typed in an empty string.

Comment: Inside the loop, one by one, along with my calculations

Comment: @khelwood and thats exactly what hes inputing if you look at how he exits the loop...

Comment: @Noah Yes I know, that's why I said that.

Answer (score 0):

Well simple. As i see your trying to Input an empty line to stop the Code:

```
elif number == "":
```

but you are allways parsing your input into an int:

```
number = int(input())
```

which for the input "" will allways through you an error.
Simply yust convert the number only after checking for exit:

```
sum = 0 
len = 0
while True:
    number = input()
    if number == "":
        break
    elif int(number) % 2 ==1:
        print(number)
        sum += int(number)
        len += 1

avg = sum/len if len > 0 else None
print(avg)
```